# is python keeping values not stored in variables to reuse them?

Tags: python

Let's suppose that I have a long dummy list:

```
dummy_long_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]*1000000
```

if I do something like:

```
while max(dummy_long_list) > 2:
    print max(dummy_long_list)
    # do some stuff that removes elements from the list
```

Here I'm using `max(dummy_long_list)` twice in each loop (in the `while` and in the `print`).

I could of course store the value in a variable:

```
max_val = max(dummy_long_list)
while max_val > 2:
    print max_val
    # do some stuff that removes elements from the list
    max_val = max(dummy_long_list)  # update max_val
```

Question: Is the first code **actually** calling the `max` function twice? Or python is smart enough?

Comment: yes, function is called twice.

Comment: Yes. python isn't smart enough.

Comment: It is calling the `max` function twice. There's nothing special about the `max` function that would let the interpreter know that calling it twice with the same argument is guaranteed to produce the same result.

Comment: in a multi-threaded environment, `dummy_long_list` could change, so the value would be different.